# bubble component Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I was looking for some angular component or library to create some sort of beautiful bubble (a single one ) with a value inside or anything similar 
I want to display a real time value of consumption that's updating on it's own

I don't want to use a gauge because I don't know the maximum value for it ,
so if you could propose anything I would be very grateful I did some searching on google but found nthg

[image]
here is an example

Comment: You should compose bubbles with CSS waiting for a value and angular to fill the value

Comment: Questions asking for off site resources are off topic on SO.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/GF5tgJpZtJZnp77wbLZn?p=preview